# QGIS not rendering WMS layers

Tags: qgis, wms

I'm a bit of newbie at GIS so be gentle with me.

In QGIS I've set up a WMS from the British Geological Survey:

http://maps.bgs.ac.uk/ArcGIS/services/BGS_Detailed_Geology/MapServer/WMSServer?

Now the layers are rendering at 1:25000 but at 1:50000 and above the screen goes blank.  According to the BGS website they should be visible between 1:75000 and 1:10000. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The scale is 1:50000 according to the BGS, so it should be fine within these parameters shouldn't it?

Comment: @sunil According to the question, Neil is within the scale range so that should not be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @GeoKevin that's true...

Comment: I don't have an answer yet, but I am seeing the same issue. In contrast, the [Hydrogeology layer](http://mapapps.bgs.ac.uk/arcgis/services/HydroMap/HydroMap/MapServer/WMSServer) comes through just fine at smaller scales.

Comment: The GetCapabilities for the service reports that it should display below 1:100000. It does this for me in QGIS so I'm guessing there may have been a problem with the scale layering in the service which is now resolved.