# QGIS still not rendering WMS layers

Tags: qgis, wms, geology

Similar to Neil's question of March 8th 2013: 
 [QGIS not rendering WMS layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53871/qgis-not-rendering-wms-layers)

I can down load the BGS 1:50K bedrock and superficial deposits maps OK, but they don't render except at scales greater than about 1:50,000 - this seems to vary; sometimes "only" 1:25000 renders correctly.

These scales are within the range quoted by the supplier (British Geological Survey).

Neil asked a very similar question, but there does not seem to be a definite explanation yet. I'm using QGIS 2.2.0-Valmeira.

Comment: Could you make a link to Neil's question, as it's not obvious what the related issue is to which you are referring.

Answer (score 5):

I loaded the [BGS 50K WMS](https://map.bgs.ac.uk/arcgis/services/BGS_Detailed_Geology/MapServer/WmsServer?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&) into QGIS 2.2.0-Valmeira (and also the [BGS 625k WMS](http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/ows?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&) as it isn't scale layered and you can check you haven't zoomed out of bounds).  I had no problem viewing the 50k WMS at various scales within the scale range of the service.

There is *possibly* an issue with layer transparency, so for example in my first image, you are only seeing the linear features layer.  The white area of no data (the are no linear features) is not shown as transparent (which logically you might expect it to be).  in my second image I have changed the global transparency to 75% and you can now see the underlying bedrock layer.

[image: BGS 50K WMS at 1:100000 in QGIS 2.2.0-Valmeira]
[image: BGS 50K WMS at 1:15,589 in QGIS 2.2.0-Valmeira]

Looking at the same WMS in ArcMap I see that the no data area is shown as transparent, so I can see through the Linear Features, mass movement, and artificial ground layers, without having to change any transparency setting.

[image: BGS 50K WMS at 1:52:603 in ArcMap 10.2.2]

As far as I can see the difference in these behaviours between ArcMap and QGIS, is that  ArcMap defaults to using the png image format for its GetMap requests, whereas QGIS picks (by default) the first listed image format in the GetCapabilities response (that it supports).

[image: image/png format selected as default]

[image: image/jpeg format selected as default]

**To get the transparent layers you must select *"png"***

Comment: Thanks, @nmtoken. Still have the problem, not a transparency issue, not a .png vs .jpg issue. What CRS do you use? I'm using OS GB 1936/BNG; i.e. that is my project format and I open the WMS download with that format. The fact that it works for you gives me hope! I'll keep on trying and post the answer when I find it. John

Comment: I used BNG (EPSG:27700) in the above tests

Comment: Is it possible that you are on a slow connection and the requests are just timing out? Do you get any error messages in QGIS?